# Modificar variables con sed

Tags: bash

Como puedo substituir con sed lo que hay después de un igual "=")
Por ejemplo, si tengo lo siguiente

```
AA=1
B=2
BB=2
C=3
CC=3
```

El valor numérico de cada uno puede cambiar, por lo que como puedo coger la variable exacta y asignarle un nuevo valor?

gracias!

Comment: No acaba de quedar clqro qué pretendes. Por otra parte, por qué con sed? Qué intentaste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para cambiar todos los valores puedes usar esto.

```
sed -ri 's/(.*)=(.*)/\1=<cambio>/g' archivo
```

Donde "<cambio>" es el valor por el que vas a cambiar todos los valores después del signo `=`. Pero cambiará todos los valores. Por ejemplo.

```
sed -ri 's/(.*)=(.*)/\1=232323/g' archivo
```

En cambio, si quieres que sea una variable específica, podrías aplicar esto.

```
sed -ri 's/(nombre de tu variable)=(.*)/\1=<cambio>/g' archivo
```

Por ejemplo:

```
sed -ri 's/(AA)=(.*)/\1=9999/g' archivo
```

El parámetro `-r` permite expresiones regulares como esta `(.*)=(.*)` que captura en dos grupos, separados por un `=`, es decir, el primer `(.*)` captura lo que esta antes del "=" y el que está después, captura lo que le sigue. El primero es el grupo 1 que se denota con `\1` y así sucesivamente con `\2`, `\3`, etc., según los grupos que hayas capturado.

El parámetro `-i` modifica el archivo y no sólo imprime en pantalla la modificación. Puedes quitar este parámetro para probar y luego se lo añades cuando te agrade la salida del texto.

Comment: gracias por la explicación @Cuauhtli

Comment: @GuifIf Espero te haya funcionado.

Comment: En general, es mejor usar el `-E` en vez del `-r` ya que el `-E` es mas portable (funciona con mas versiones de sed). El `-r` es cosa del GNU `sed`, lo que esta en Linux, pero varias otras versiones no lo tienen. También, el `g` no hace nada aquí.

Answer (score 2):

En general, cuanto trabajas con expresiones regulares, la regla es "menos es mas". Es decir, es mejor usar la expresión mas minima que funcione por lo que quieras, ya que cuanto mas compleja, mas probable será que alguna linea de tu entrada no la cumplirá.

En este caso, te interesa solo la parte después del `=`, así que puedes simplemente hacer:

```
sed 's/=[0-9]*/=foo/' fichero > nuevo.fichero
```

Eso cambiará todos los números que se encuentran después del primero `=` en cada línea con `foo`. Si quieres hacer el cambio en el fichero original, usa el `-i`:

```
sed -i 's/=[0-9]*/=foo/' fichero
```

Si puedes tener otra cosa que números, quieres:

```
sed -i 's/=.*/=foo/' fichero
```